# inverse_transform() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm trying to use Canonical Correlation Analysis [`(CCA)` in scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_decomposition.CCA.html). Still, I'm getting a `TypeError`, which asserts `inverse_transform() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`.

Here is my code:

```py
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.cross_decomposition import CCA
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV


mycca = CCA(n_components=4)
mycca.fit(x, y)
x, y = mycca.transform(x, y)
x_test = mycca.transform(x_test)


parameters = {
'n_estimators': [50 , 100, 200, 300],
'max_depth': [3, 5, 6 ,8 , 9 ,10]
}
modell = RandomForestRegressor(max_leaf_nodes=2)
modell = RandomizedSearchCV(modell,
                            param_distributions=parameters,
                            cv=5,
                            n_iter=10,
                            n_jobs=-1
)
modell.fit(x , y)
predicted = modell.predict(x_test).flatten()
mycca.inverse_transform(x_test, predicted)
```

And the last line throws a `TypeError`:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-7d035a65b067> in <module>
----> 1 mycca.inverse_transform(x_test, predicted)

TypeError: inverse_transform() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

It's ridiculous since I passed two arguments exactly, named `x_test` and `predicted`. If you're curious about shape of `x_test` and `predicted`:

```py
>>>x_test.shape, predicted.shape
((1, 4), (4,))

>>>x_test, predicted
(array([[-0.36689807, -0.03637745,  0.1099326 , -0.22595879]]),
 array([-0.02223153, -0.11932753,  0.08806947, -0.0044004 ]))
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not counting the "self" argument that is given to the method when calling it. This means the third argument is the instance of CCA class which is "mycca".
try:

```
mycca.inverse_transform(X=x_test, Y=predicted)
```

If your are using version 1.0.2 then you will get an error as this is not supported in that version.This is for version 1.0.2:[image]

This one is the newest version:
[image]

Comment: `TypeError: inverse_transform() got an unexpected keyword argument 'Y'`

Comment: To be able to pass Y you should update the module

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget this is a method, so one of the arguments is always `self`.
Handling `Y` for cross decomposition `inverse_transform()` was added not so long ago (sklearn 1.0.1 I believe), perhaps your version is too old.
Alternatively, try invoking `inverse_transform()` with `x_test` only.

Comment: I'm using sklearn version `1.0.2`. But the [official doc](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_decomposition.CCA.html#sklearn.cross_decomposition.CCA.inverse_transform) shows two positional arguments.

Comment: At the very least, I am unable to reproduce this error with 1.1.1 here. Perhaps installing something with a package manager pulled in an obsolete version? What does `from sklearn import __version__ ; print(__version__)` and `help(CCA.inverse_transform)` say?